# what is 'named type'

Tags: c#

I often come across the term 'named type' in C#. What does it mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A type that has been explicitly declared with a name. For example, any class or a struct you declare is a named type.

There are also anonymous types, which are declared without a name and the compiler assigns a name to that type which is not accessible to the developer.

You can read more on the different types of [types in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

This is in reference to variables that are **explicitly typed**, as opposed to those which have an anonymous type.  Anything that is not an anonymous type is a named type.

Introduced with (I think) .Net 3.0, anonymous types provided a convenient way of creating objects containing a set of *read-only* properties, without having to define an explicitly named type for that purpose.

Although the implementation of anonymous types also requires the use of [**type inference**](http://www.developer.com/net/csharp/article.php/3601646/Go-Inside-C-30s-Type-Inference-Process.htm) (for the typing of the properties of the object), **anonymous types are not to be confused with** [**Implicitly Typed Local Variables**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) whereby the ***var*** keyword frees the programmer of explicitly stating a variable type, but where a type is effectively provided by the compiler.  (most implicitly typed variables are not anonymous types and are therefore a named type.  It's just the compiler that does the naming).

Comment: This is wrong.  Type inference and anonymous types are not related.  Type inference can be used in some cases to exclude generic parameters or with the var keyword.  Anonymous types are unnamed types that are created on the fly.

Comment: @recursive  Thank you! I read-up on this and realize where I went wrong.  Type Inference is often used in the case of anonymous types, but, the two concepts are indeed completely separate.  I'll fix my response accordingly (or kill it altogether...)

Comment: Thks, you didn't need to do that, the downvote was well deserved: I spoked, well wrote, too fast!  More importantly, thks for teaching me something, today.

Answer (score 2):

Any type which is not a [Annonymous Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) would be a "Named Type".

Comment: By your definition, two-dimensional-array-of-integers is a named type.  Does that actually make sense? If so, what's its name?

Comment: @Eric Thanks for reading this question. Please throw more light on this discussion if you feel there is anything missing or misunderstood.

Answer (score 2):

A named type is any explicitly defined type (struct, class, etc.) that you create and give a name.

e.g.:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar{ get; set; }
}
```

In this case, Foo is a named type.

This is as opposed to an anonymous type, which is typically created on the fly:

```
var MyFoo = new { Bar = "some text" };
```

I just created a new object, called MyFoo.  We haven't explicitly given it a type name, but we have implicitly given it a String property, Bar, with the value "some text".

Comment: from MJV's comment above, 'Var MyFoo' means implicitly typed variable. How is this anonymous type as you have mentioned? thanks